# Laravel eloquent get most repeated 10 products

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have an `export_invoices` table which contain invoices.

```
+----+----------------+
| id | title          |
+----+----------------+
| 1  | First Invoice  |
+----+----------------+
| 2  | Second Invoice |
+----+----------------+
```

And `sold_products` which have relationship with `export_invoices`.

```
+----+-------------------+------------+
| id | export_invoice_id | product_id |
+----+-------------------+------------+
| 1  | 1                 | 1          |
+----+-------------------+------------+
| 2  | 1                 | 1          |
+----+-------------------+------------+
| 3  | 1                 | 2          |
+----+-------------------+------------+
| 4  | 2                 | 1          |
+----+-------------------+------------+
| 5  | 2                 | 1          |
+----+-------------------+------------+
```

What I expect to get:

I expect to get that `product_id = 1 is repeated 2 times` and `product_id = 2 is repeated 1 time`

Which means the frequency of repeating product in invoices.

Comment: And what have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: If it was the most repeated 3 products, how would you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to go at it from the products side, assuming you have a relationship setup between products and invoices

```php
$products = App\Product::withCount('export_invoices')->get();
```

This will return a collection of all products, each product will have a property called `export_invoices_count` that states how many Export Invoices that Product appears on. You can then sort this collection by `export_invoices_count` and take the first 10.

```
$top_ten = $products->sortByDesc('export_invoices_count')->take(10);
```

Comment: This return `export_invoices_counter` always equal `1`